# Changing a specific element's CSS without an ID in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div unique="custom name">
  <span class="outer">
    <ol>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
    </ol>
  </span>
</div>
```

How can the CSS for the `ol` be changed through Javascript, when all that is known is the name of the `unique` attribute for the div and the fact that an `ol` is contained within it? Is this even possible? I know that this would be the CSS code to access it on a document-level:

```
div[unique="custom name"] ol {
  color: blue;
}
```

There's no `id` to the div and it cannot be added, so I need to be able to change the CSS with respect to the `unique` attribute.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or any JavaScript framework ?

Comment: [**Please search before posting**](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+find+element+without+id)

Comment: Technically, this is possible, however, you should add id or class to the elements that you want to apply styles to make it easier and clearer

Comment: @ntahoang - I'm not in charge of the content of the page on that level, so I cannot add an `id` or `class`, otherwise I would -- because I know that would be a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - I did search -- both on the web and on SO, but I didn't get that result, otherwise, I wouldn't have posted. My search terms must not have been precise enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector()` to do this: It finds the first element in the document matching a CSS selector. (There's also `document.querySelectorAll`, which returns a list of all matching elements.)

Select your element using `document.querySelector("div[unique='custom name'] ol")` and then add the required styles

```js
document.querySelector("div[unique='custom name'] ol").style.color = "blue";
```

```html
<div unique="custom name">
  <span class="outer">
    <ol>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
    </ol>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: And, to access the color attribute to check what it is, would I just enter `document.querySelector("div[unique='custom name'] ol").style.color` -- or would that require a different command?

Comment: @J.D. it doesn't require a different command, you can just use the above one